# What is fundamental period of sum of two discrete time sinusoidal functions with same period?

Tags: trigonometry, signal-processing, periodic-functions

If I think of example like   $\quad -sin[\pi n]+sin[\pi n] \;$

Although both functions have the same fundamental period 2, fundamental period of their sum is undefined. 
So how can I deal with the **fundamental period of**

$\; cos\left[\dfrac{7\pi n}{10}\right]+sin\left[\dfrac{13\pi n}{10}\right] \;$

They both have 20 as their fundamental period, but as I know from the first example that we cannot simply apply **least common multiple rule.** Are there any simple rules for solving these problems ?

Comment: This first example is zero though.

Comment: In the textbook I am using (Signals and Systems by Alan Oppenheim) it is said that the constant discrete-time signal resulting from setting $\;w_0=0\;$ has a fundamental frequency of zero, and its fundamental period is undefined.

Comment: Can you apply the LCM rule with the caveat that the function is non-constant?

Comment: I think yes. So if we consider sum of periodic discrete time sinusoidal functions it is enough to check whether resulting function is constant. If it is not we can simply find $T_0$ via LCM. Thanks :)